# How to make multiple colors in a border in GIMP?

Tags: color, gimp, borders

Im trying to search on the internet, but nothing i found what i want, heres the example of what i mean.

[image: Heres a border with multiple colors, i don't want gradient colors, i want like this in the image.]

Thank you for your response. :)

By the way i just screenshot it from the China Uncensored video. :)

Comment: You can create a custom hard gradient for that, and use the gradient tool to fill a selection.

Comment: @Billy Kerr Ok i will try this. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You define a gradient with the colors needed, and set the transition type as "step". You can use the gradient editor for this, but a shortcut is to define a palette with the colors, and in the Palettes list right click the palette and `Palette to repeating gradient`. Then you just edit the result to set the blending function to `Step` in each segment. If necessary you can move the stops to change the relative length of each color.

[image]

2. In the Paintbrush options you set:

   - the `Brush size` to the thickness of the line
   - the `Dynamics` to `Gradient`
   - `Fade options/Fade length` to the length of the color cycle
   - `Fade options/Repeat` to `Sawtooth wave`
   - `Gradient` to the gradient your created (but it is likely already done)

[image]

Then to make a border, you create a rectangle selection, and use `Edit > Stroke selection` with `Stroke with a paint tool` and `Emulate brush dynamics`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay i will try this, i appreciate your help, because you put effort on it and detailed info, thank you very much! :)